# the dtype parameter in numpy genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to create MX2 numpy matrix or array from the following file contents:

```
shell: head WORLD#America.csv
"2013-04-17 12","3","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 13","9","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 14","4","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 15","3","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 16","7","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 17","8","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 18","6","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 19","6","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 20","6","WORLD","#America"
"2013-04-17 21","2","WORLD","#America"
```

I have come across the `genfromtxt()` function but have been unsuccessful in extracting my data. With a file  called `f` I tried the following: `ts = genfromtxt(f, delimiter=",")` and got an array filled all with `nan`. This was only a first attempt, so I read the documentation about the `dtype` parameter which specifies the data-type of the array. It appears that to get an MX2 matrix with entries of the form `(datetime, int)` I would have the following: `dtype=[('f1', datetime64), ('f2', uint)]`. When I did this, I got the following assigned to variable `ts`:

```
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L),
(datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 18446744073709551615L)],
dtype=[('f1', ('<M8[us]', {})), ('f2', '<u8')])
```

Every value I got for the matrix is some constant... Why did it not read from my file?
Obviously this is not the output that I should get.

How do I get the desired MX2 matrix or array with the first column being the `datetime` and the second column being an integer as shown with the head command?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664790/reading-csv-files-in-numpy-where-delimiter-is I suspect your quotes are causing trouble, and you'll need to write converters manually.

Comment: The first item in the first column is `"2013-04-17 12"`.  What is the meaning of `12` in that field?  Is it the hour of the day, or a separate data field?

Comment: Hour of day, correct!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, one difficulty in reading this file with `genfromtxt` is the presence of quote characters. Maybe it's best to just (programmatically) remove the quotes, but it's also possible to cheat around the issue: Specify the quote character as the delimiter:

```
np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter='"', dtype=str, comments=None)[0]
# array(['', '2013-04-17 12', ',', '3', ',', 'WORLD', ',', '#America', ''], 
#       dtype='|S13')
```

Now the file is interpreted as having 9 columns, where the second and fourth column contain the data of interest.

Another problem is to specify the dtype for the date-time column. In more recent(?) versions of Numpy you have to specify the time/date unit or `genfromtxt` throws an error. In this case apparently you need to use `M8[h]` as the dtype, to specify an hourly unit.

All in all, I was able to load the file with:

```
ts = np.genfromtxt(filename, 
                   delimiter='"', 
                   dtype='M8[h], uint', 
                   usecols=[1,3])
```

Alternatively, you could look into [using a converter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#the-converters-argument) or try [the CSV reader from Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).